# DynamoDB encryption at rest with Global tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was looking through the docs for DynamoDB encryption at rest as per here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.howitworks.html

I tried to look into the usage of native encryption from DynamoDB for the usage of global tables, but I couldn't find one. Is using encryption for global tables not an option right now? Are there any specific docs which point to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

**Q.  How does encryption at rest work with DynamoDB Global Tables?**

> You can enable encryption at rest on your Global Table replicas. Note that Global Tables uses DynamoDB Streams, which does not yet support Encryption at Rest. As a result, replicated data on DynamoDB Streams will not be encrypted at rest.

Comment: Thank you for that. I wish this showed up somewhere more easily visible

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.usagenotes.html

In summary, both Global Table and Update Streams support Encryption at Rest now.

> You can use streams with encrypted tables. Encryption at rest encrypts the data in DynamoDB streams. For more information, see Capturing Table Activity with DynamoDB Streams.
>
> You can use global tables with encrypted tables. Encryption at rest encrypts the data in global tables. For more information, see Global Tables.